# Dot plot of multiple X and Y variables?

Tags: r, plot

I am using a gene expression dataset from ~100 cells.

I want to generate a dot plot indicating which cells are expressing which genes, like below, excluding the color delineations.

[image: expected dot plot]

I have tried ggplot solutions, but (from what I can tell) Ggplot2 cannot graph numerous variables in each axis. I've looked into more complex packages like Seurot and cRegulome (the image above is from cRegulome), but these produce more information the graphical output than I want.

Below is an example of the type of data frame I am working with.

```
Cell_A<-c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
Cell_B<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
Cell_C<-c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
Cell_D<-c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
Cell_E<-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
Cell_F<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)
Cell_G<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Cell_H<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Genes <- c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene3","Gene4","Gene5","Gene6","Gene7","Gene8") 

fake_data <- data.frame(Cell_A, Cell_B, Cell_C, Cell_D, Cell_E, 
Cell_F, Cell_G,Cell_H, row.names = Genes)
```

How can I manipulate this dataset to get the graphical output I want?

Comment: *"I have tried ggplot solutions"* -- can you post what you've tried? Also, your sample plot shows varied dot sizes and colors, but your data is all 0s and 1s, is there something else that should be going on?

Comment: I'd think you're first want to reshape from wide-to-long (plenty of questions on SO about that) before sending to `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by reshaping the data and using `geom_point`. Map the `size` aesthetic to your count variable and it will work well. The legend is currently a bit nonsensical but can be manually tweaked if you do not have any other sizes than 0 and 1.

```r
library(tidyverse)
Cell_A<-c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
Cell_B<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
Cell_C<-c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
Cell_D<-c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
Cell_E<-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
Cell_F<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)
Cell_G<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Cell_H<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Genes <- c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene3","Gene4","Gene5","Gene6","Gene7","Gene8") 

fake_data <- data.frame(Cell_A, Cell_B, Cell_C, Cell_D, Cell_E, 
                        Cell_F, Cell_G,Cell_H, row.names = Genes)

fake_data %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "gene") %>%
  gather(cell, count, -gene) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = gene, y = cell, size = count))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: (Not everybody has all of `tidyverse`: this requires `tibble`, `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `ggplot2`.)

Comment: An option to avoid a continuous-scale on `count` (I'm assuming it is integral) would be either `size=factor(count)` (yuck) or adding `+ scale_size_continuous(breaks=0:1)` (barely better) to the ggplot-chain.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I will need to to remove all dots at non expressing points (=0), and to control the size of the expressing points (=1)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a base R solution that relies on `matplot()`.

```
fake_data2 <- sweep(fake_data, 2, seq_len(length(fake_data)), FUN = '*')
fake_data2[fake_data2 == 0] <- NA_integer_

matplot(x = seq_along(Genes), y = as.matrix(fake_data2), 
        , cex = colSums(fake_data) / 3, pch = 16, col = 1
        , yaxt='n', xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)

axis(1, at = seq_along(Genes), Genes)
axis(2, at = seq_len(length(fake_data)), names(fake_data), las = 1)
```

You didn't provide enough details on how what size you wanted. The size here is based on the number of `1` values for each column.

[image: matplot Base R graph]